# What exactly is the only Sylow $3$-Subgroup of $D_3$?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, dihedral-groups

I can apply the needed theorem to get me to the fact that it only has one Sylow $3$-Subgroup but I donʻt know how to find exactly what it is. I have the multiplication table computed so help in regards using the table specifically would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is exactly one group of order three up to isomorphism. Since $3$ is prime, $3\mid 6$, and $6$ is the order of $D_3$, Cauchy's Theorem gives us at least one element $r$ of $D_3$ of order three. It then follows that your subgroup is $\{e, r, r^2\}$.

Comment: Yes the above comment lead me down this road...thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, @PhysicsBish. After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Find a subgroup of order $3$. This is a Sylow subgroup. Like you said, there is only one. It is generated by an element of order $3$. Find such an element.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: @PhysicsBish You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as an alternative to the other answers, note that $D_3\cong S_3$.  Since the Sylow $3$ subgroup has order $3$, and $(123)$ has order $3$, it is $\langle (123)\rangle$.

This must be, under an isomorphism, the same as the subgroup generated by a rotation through $2\pi/3$.  Namely $\langle r\rangle=\{e,r,r^2\}$.

Comment: Cool thanks for that, the more ways to look at it the better. I have seen some examples of looking at what the group is isomorphic to and going from there, so its nice to see it in my example. :)

Comment: You bet.  @PhysicsBish